Mufla samuch l'ish (מופלא סמוך לאיש)
In the fifth perek of Nidah (45b), one of the mishnayos discusses the idea of מופלא סמוך לאיש. It's a boy or girl a year before bar or bas mitzvah, and they are considered an adult in exactly one way: assuming they understand what they're doing (יודעים לשם מי נודרים), they can make valid vows or oaths, or hekdesh, and similar things.
The gemara there 46(a,b) brings various opinions on what this causes: Is it (a) the person himself or herself is held responsible (before bar or bas mitzvah!) and could get lashes if they violated the neder, or (b) even if the person isn't personally responsible, others are responsible to stop the person from violating the oath. Or (c) at least others would be responsible and get malkus if they themselves violated the oath. Or lastly perhaps (d) the entire law is only מדרבן.
My question is: How unique is this? We know there are generally laws of chinuch to prepare a child for bar and bas mitzvah. There are also some laws of various kinds of kinyanim that children can make at various ages ("אגוז ונוטלו", "knows enough to keep a nut and throw away a rock"...) But this seems kind of unique, only for this one class of laws alone. How does it fit in?
And, aside from the drashos if it's m'd'oraysa, are there reasons given for why the Torah imposes this? Or, if it is indeed completely d'rabanan ((d) above), why did Chazal enact this?
